# Delphi VCL Style Issue - Minimize MDI Child Form with WinWidth Constraints not showing Border icons (Restore, Maximize, Close)

Tags: delphi, vcl, vcl-styles

Im running Delphi XE5 - also tested on Delphi XE7 had the same issue

If you minimize a MDI child form that has its MinWidth Constraint set to something above 200 ish the border Icons ( Min Max Close ) are no longer visible - or get chopped off

**Steps to reproduce**

Create a new VCL project
set the main form "FormStyle" to fsMDIForm
Add a new Form to the project
Set the "FormStyle" to fsMDIChild
Set the MDI Child Form "Constraints".MinWidth to 500
Apply a Style to the Project
Project - options - Application - Set to Enable Runtime themes
Project - options - Application - Appearance - Select "Lavender Classico" and set the default style to "Lavender Classico"

run the application
open the child form
Minimize the child form
you will notice that the ( Min Max Close buttons are no longer visible )

does anyone know of a workaround for this?

---

**Temp Fix**

this is what i'm doing at the moment, until i find something better.
i don't believe this is the answer so iv'e put it here

created a unit with the following

```
procedure StyleFix_FormConstrainedResize(FormWindowState : TWindowState; var FormCurrentMinWidth : integer;Const MIN_WIDTH_VALUE : integer);

implementation

procedure StyleFix_FormConstrainedResize(FormWindowState : TWindowState; var FormCurrentMinWidth : integer;
          Const MIN_WIDTH_VALUE : integer);
begin
  if (FormWindowState = wsMinimized) then begin
    if  ( FormCurrentMinWidth > 0 ) then
      FormCurrentMinWidth := 0;
  end else if FormCurrentMinWidth <> MIN_WIDTH_VALUE then begin
    FormCurrentMinWidth := MIN_WIDTH_VALUE;
  end;
end;
```

and any form that has a minimum width constraint adding the unit to the uses clause and adding the procedure to the

```
uses xStyleFixes;
```

...

```
procedure TfrmSubForm.FormConstrainedResize(Sender: TObject; var MinWidth,
          MinHeight, MaxWidth, MaxHeight: Integer);
begin
  StyleFix_FormConstrainedResize(self.WindowState, MinWidth, 500);
end;
```

i couldn't find a way to auto get the original min width setting
so where 500 above has been hardcoded if will have to be manually entered each time depending on what you have

Comment: Does the constraint work after you restore the form?

Comment: I need 10 rep to add an image.  After restoring the form the Min, Max, Close icons are ok. only when minimized the buttons are not visible

Comment: After restoring the form, the minimum width constraints still work

Comment: Thanks. With XE2 it didn't, code has obviously changed.

Comment: i just tested with XE2 and the minimum width constraint got changed from 500 to 160 after the form was restored. Icons still not showing correctly

Comment: You might try not using MDI (which has been deprecated for years) with VCL styles. MDI in Windows has always been poor, and MS (and most of the rest of the world) stopped using it years ago. It's hardly surprising that trying to shoehorn styles on top of it has issues.

Comment: i did not know that its been depreciated.  Sadly its not going to be a 5 minute change to move away from it. was hoping for a quick fix

Comment: I can't see mdi ever being removed since it is still used. However, I also can't see vcl styles working with it. That's an unholy mix if ever there was one.

Comment: This  has got nothing to do with MDI. I can duplicate the same bugs with top level windows in XE2, just make a form minimize on the desktop - not on the taskbar. I expect same to happen in XE7 too.

Comment: @Sertac Are you suggesting that VCL styles are in some way defective?

Comment: @David LOL!. I hope I haven't gone too far ...